# ImportError: cannot import name util, while trying to install arosics on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

While trying to install AROSICS (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arosics/0.8.2) on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I do:

```
~$ sudo pip install arosics
```

Then I get:

```
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting arosics
  Downloading arosics-0.8.4.tar.gz (21.9MB)
    100% |################################| 21.9MB 32kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-PRYU7V/arosics/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from importlib import util
    ImportError: cannot import name util

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PRYU7V/arosics/
```

Also tried:

```
sudo -H pip install arosics
Collecting arosics
  Downloading arosics-0.8.4.tar.gz (21.9MB)
    100% |################################| 21.9MB 23kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cTU5Br/arosics/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from importlib import util
    ImportError: cannot import name util

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cTU5Br/arosics/
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong. I tried to `pip install python-util` but event after that I keep getting the same error above.

May I ask how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Arosics currently will only work with Python3. `from importutil import util` does not work under Python 2.7 as it is not supported.

If switching to Python3 is an option you are good to go. If not, the Arosics project's setup.py will have to be modified.

I was able to install successfully with `sudo pip3 install arosics`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in version 0.8.14 of arosics. It should now be compatible to Python 2.7 again.

However, go for Python 3!